# Wait until multiple processes are running

Tags: bash

I want to wait until three processes are running, so I am using an `until` loop. This works when checking one process:

```
until pgrep my-process; do echo "waiting…"; done
```

However, I am unable to add additional conditions. If I wrap the condition in single or double square brackets, I get errors. Specifically, these both fail.

```
until [[ pgrep my-process ]]; do echo "waiting…"; done
until [ pgrep my-process ]; do echo "waiting…"; done
```

I am unsure how to do multiple conditions if square brackets aren't working for the first case.

Comment: Why do you think you need/want square brackets here at all?

Comment: I have only ever seen multiple conditions accomplished with square brackets.

Comment: `until pgrep my-process && pgrep my-other-process; do`

Comment: Square brackets are `test` syntax -- that is to say, `[` is an alias for the command named `test`. You don't want to run the command `test`, you want to run the command `pgrep` (twice).

Answer (score 3):

Square brackets are not involved in combining multiple conditions.

```
until pgrep my-process && pgrep my-other-process && pgrep my-last-process; do
  echo "waiting..."
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: So why does every question that talks about multiple conditions in an `if` statement or `while` loop use square brackets?

Comment: @Josephus Both `[...]` and `[[...]]` are just one of many commands that can make up the condition of a loop. The condition is just an arbitrary command list, not necessarily a conditional expression.

Comment: @Josephus, `test` conditions (checking file existence, executability; checking whether strings / shell variables are empty or not; etc) are one of the most common kinds of conditions people test in their scripts. That doesn't mean that *every* conditional will use `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets aren't used for command grouping. They actually do a completely different set of conditionals; you can use square brackets for just one condition, and you can do multiple conditions without square brackets.

What `until`, `while`, etc. all do is they *run the command* specified (`pgrep my-process` in your example) and do the condition based on the command's exit code. `[` and `[[` are just *specific examples* of commands that are often useful for testing things.

To combine multiple conditions, you can use `&&` for "and" and `||` for "or" (the `[[` and `[` commands have their own internal syntax for combining but you could also use `&&` and `||` for them if you wanted). For more complex operations, you can use parentheses for grouping.

Comment: It's noteworthy that the syntax for combining tests in `[` is marked obsolescent in the current version of the POSIX standard -- search for the `OB` markers in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Interesting; I did not know that. I’ll include both that and a link to [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/q/52034) when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
until (( `pgrep my-process |wc -l` > 2 )); do
  echo "waiting..."
  sleep 1
done
```

The `((` notation is for numeric comparisons.  The `wc -l` shows number of lines which in this case means number of processes.